# Set cursor in To: field while sending mail programmatically from iPad

Tags: ipad

I am sending an email programmatically from my iPad app.
What I want is when the mail view appears, the cursor should be seen blinking in the "To" field and the keyboard should also appears at the same time.
Can anybody help on this?